# mysql match / against syntax

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a varchar column in my db that I'd like to search for words using a mysql `MATCH / AGAINST` query. However, if there's multiple words it doesn't appear to be working.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (title) VALUES ('my id 123');

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+my +id +123' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Returns no results. Am I missing something in the query syntax? Note that the `title` field does not have a full-text index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my`, `id` & `123` are probably lower then [`ft_min_word_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). I hesitated whether numerics would be considered words, a quick test reveals they are, but the minimum (string)length still applies.

Comment: @wrikken-- there's no fulltext index, so does the ft_min_word_length apply?

Comment: @user101289: Yes, according the [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html): _"The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply."_

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the following:

STEP 01: Create a stopword list

```
echo "a"    > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "an"  >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

This will prevent indexing the most comment word articles

STEP 02 : Add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_length=1
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

STEP 03 : Restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

STEP 04 : Create the FULLTEXT index

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FULLTEXT ft_title (title);
```

Afterwards, your query should work, or at least produce tangible results.

Give it a Try !!!